# why on clicking on edit button of childgridview the childgridview hides?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

This is what I have done for nested gridview :

The jQuery I have used to maintain this show hide is as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Method for managing opening of gridview on + image and - image

    $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "../Image/minus.gif");
    });

    $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function() {

        $(this).attr("src", "../Image/plus.gif");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();

    });
</script>


<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" DataKeyNames="num"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" Style="font-size: x-small" OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging"
    OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelling" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
    OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"  ShowFooter="True"
    OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting"
    AllowSorting="true">
    <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="../Image/plus.gif"  />
                <asp:Panel  ID="pnlOrders" style="display:none;">


                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" DataKeyNames="sno"
                        OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView3_RowCancelling" OnRowUpdating="GridView3_RowUpdating"
                        OnRowEditing="GridView3_RowEditing" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Style="font-size: x-small">
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                            Detailed Head
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>

                                    <asp:Label ID="empdetails" Width="200px" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Details") %>'></asp:Label>
                                     </ItemTemplate> 
                              <EditItemTemplate>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtempdetail" Width="200px" runat="server" MaxLength="9" Text='<%# Eval("Details") %>'>
                                    </asp:TextBox>
                              </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="sal" HeaderText="salary" />
                            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" EditText="Edit"  />
                        </Columns>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    </asp:GridView>

                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="View" runat="server" Text="View" CommandName="view"
                    CommandArgument='<%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Age</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblage" Width="80px" runat="server" MaxLength="4" Text='<%# Eval("age") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtage" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("age") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                BloodGroup</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblBloodGroup" Width="100px" runat="server" MaxLength="9" Text='<%# Eval(" BloodGroup") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBloodGroup" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval(" BloodGroup") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Select" />
        <asp:CommandField DeleteText="Reject" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" EditText="Edit" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

On server side this is what I am doing:

```
 protected void GridView3_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        tBL objBL = new tBL();
        GridViewRow editedRow = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
        //now search row for your control...
        GridView GridView3 = (GridView)editedRow.FindControl("GridView3");

        GridView3.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

        objtxtToTableBL.ViewBL(dt);
        GridView3.DataSource = dt;
        GridView3.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView3_RowCancelling(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    }

    protected void GridView3_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

I am binding the nested `gridview` on `rowdatabound` of `GridView1` and that works fine.

The problem with all this is when I click on the edit button of innergridview(child) it get hide as the page postback .

What should I do so that when I click on its edit button the child gridview remains open and it gets hides only when I click on minus button. Please help it has already taken 3 days of mine.

Comment: That's a loooooot of irrelevant code... Provide a **fiddle** with your specific problem

Comment: so what else i should provide ? server code ?

Comment: @Rambo_Raja: where are you binding the GridView1 in the code behind?